# Can not check form values with a ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a catalog of classified grouped by categories.

However when I submit my form, I get the following error message:

```
Caught ValueError while rendering: Cannot assign "u'9'": "Classified.category" must be a "Category" instance.
```

I believe this is because Django expects a Category objects instead of a simple integer which corresponds to the chosen Category ID.

Here is how I wrote the system:
A classified is linked to one category.
The category system is hierarchical with a parent category and a list of child categories.
For example I have something like this:

```
Electronics
    |-- IPad
    |-- IPods
    |-- ...
```

So I have the following models:

```py
class Category(BaseModel):
    # [...]
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', slugify=slugify, unique=True,
        unique_with='name', max_length=255, default='')
    parent = models.IntegerField(u'parent', max_length=10, null=False,
            default=0)

    objects = CategoryManager()

    # [...]

class Classified(BaseModel):
    # [...]
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='classifieds')
```

I created the following manager:

```py
class CategoryManager(Manager):
    def categoryTree(self):
        tree = self.raw("SELECT"
            " P.id, P.name parent_name, P.slug parent_slug, P.id parent_id,"
            " C.name child_name, C.slug child_slug, C.id child_id"
            " FROM classified_category C"
            " LEFT JOIN classified_category P ON P.id = C.parent"
            " WHERE C.parent <> 0"
            " ORDER BY P.name, C.name;")

        categoryTree = []

        current_parent_id = tree[0].parent_id
        current_parent_name = tree[0].parent_name
        option_list = []

        for c in tree:
            if current_parent_id != c.parent_id:
                categoryTree.append((current_parent_name, option_list))
                option_list = []
                current_parent_id = c.parent_id
                current_parent_name = c.parent_name

            option_list.append((c.child_id, c.child_name))

        categoryTree.append((current_parent_name, option_list))

        return category
```

And my Django form contains the following:

```py
class ClassifiedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # [...]

    category = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Category', required=True,
            choices=Category.objects.categoryTree(), widget=forms.Select())
    # [...]
```

If I use category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category.objects.all()) everything works fine but I need to control how the `<select>` field is displayed with a list of `<optgroup>`. This is why use categoryTree()
But unfortunately using CategoryManager.categoryTree() breaks my form validation and I do not know how to fix my problem.

If I could be pointed to where I was wrong and how I can fix this, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is to save category manually

```
class ClassifiedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # [...]

    category = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Category', required=True,
            choices=Category.objects.categoryTree(), widget=forms.Select())

    class Meta:
        exclude=('category',)

    def save(self):
        classified = super(ClassifiedForm, self).save(commit=False)
        classified.category = Category.objects.get(id=self.cleaned_data['category'])
        classified.save()
        return classified
```

Answer (score 0):

You can and should still use a ModelChoiceField. The list of choices can be modified in the **init** method of the form class - i.e.

```
class ClassifiedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassifiedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the queryset for validation purposes. 
        # May not be necessary if categoryTree contains all categories
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.categoryTreeObjects() 

        # Set the choices
        self.fields['category'].choices = Category.objects.categoryTree()
```

Also, you should look carefully at the [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/) package. It looks like you may be reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: It could work if `categoryTree()` returned queryset. But it doesn't.

Comment: From what he's posted, categoryTree returns a tuple of choices. As you can see, I'm assigning that to the choices attribute of the category field. I've invented another function (which he'll need to write) called categoryTreeObjects for the queryset attribute.

Comment: Ok, it can work, but two "parallel" functions isn't the best thing for maintaining. And BTW `queryset` attr isn't just for validation purposes, `save` logic is also based heavily on it. That's why I don't like `ModelForm`.

Comment: How do you mean the save logic is based on it? My understanding is that the queryset's only purpose within the field is to provide the source from which the to_python method extracts the appropriate object. If the object doesn't exist, to_python raises a ValidationError. See here: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py#L974

Comment: DrTyrsa : You said `categoryTree()` could work if it returned a queryset. Even though I agree with you I am not sure I can translate my current raw SQL query into an Django Queryset by using the Models API. Can I ?